# How to install latest Xdebug 2.2.4 on Zend Server CE 6.3.0 with PHP 5.5.7 on Windows 7

Tags: php, xdebug, zend-server

I'm having problem installing XDebug on my Zend Server running on Windows 7.
Theoretically, based on http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/content/zend_server_php_5.5_extensions.htm it looks like Zend Server 6.3 should come with XDebug extension loaded, but it's not in my case.

So I moved to manual installation and using the XDebug tailer installation instructions I get following results

```
Xdebug installed: no
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: yes - Install path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer
PHP Version: 5.5.7
Thread Safe Build: no
```

My first question was, which version I should download since there's no XDebug version for PHP 5.5 and VC9, there's only VC11 version. I ended up trying both VC11 for PHP 5.5 and VC9 for PHP 5.4.

Then I followed instructrion from the XDebug page - doesn't work,
then more instructions from http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=553

Nothing worked, no XDebug info showing on phpinfo page, or Zend Server PHP configuration page.
Can anyone suggest how can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.5 is generally build only with VC11, see on windows.php.net

So the automatic download from http://pecl.php.net or xdebug site is also build only with VC11.

You have multiple choices:

- build xdebug yourself with VC9, instructions here: https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild
- treat Zend that they finally build PHP5.5 with VC11, like everybody else already do
- downgrade ZendServer to PHP 5.4

**//UPDATE: VC9 build are now available**
http://xdebug.org/download.php

Comment: I ended up downgrading PHP to 5.4, but thanks for more options :)

Comment: @Marrbacca see update of my answer, VC9 build are now available :-)